# Perl Net::SMTP::SSL error on Mac OS: "malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff8929d50d: pointer being freed was not allocated"

Tags: macos, perl, ssl, smtp

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.2 with Perl 5.12.4 (the version that comes with it).

I installed Net::SMTP::SSL via CPAN ('sudo cpan', then 'install Net::SMTP::SSL')

Whenever I try to use the perl module, I get an error that looks like:

```
perl(41125) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff8929d50d: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I've tried to simplify this down as much as possible to narrow down the error.  In the following code, it will crash when it tries to run the `$smtp->auth` line (right after the "About to crash" line).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::SMTP::SSL;

$mailhost           = 'foo.bar.com';
$sender             = 'baz@foo.bar.com';
$sender_acct        = 'baz';
$sender_name        = 'Foo Bar';
$sender_password    = 'password';
$subject            = 'Auto notice';
$userEmail          = 'user@foo.bar.com';
$thisMessage        = "Hello from Foo Bar\n";

our $smtp = new Net::SMTP::SSL(
                   $mailhost,
                   Port    =>       465,
                   #Debug   =>        1,
                   #Hello   =>       'foo.bar.com',
                   #Timeout =>      10
                   ) or die "Could not set up SMTP $!\n$smtp->message";

print "About to crash\n";

# -- Authorize ourselves with the SMTP server --
$smtp->auth($sender_acct, $sender_password);

#  -- Enter sender mail address. --
$smtp->mail($sender);

#  -- Enter recipient mails address. --
@success = $smtp->recipient($userEmail,  { SkipBad => 1 });

$smtp->data();

# -- This part creates the SMTP headers you see. --
$smtp->datasend("To: <$userEmail> \n");
$smtp->datasend("From: $sender_name <$sender> \n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: $subject");

# -- line break to separate headers from message body. --
$smtp->datasend("\n");

$smtp->datasend($thisMessage);

$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->dataend();
$smtp->quit();
```

I'm pretty confident it's not an error in my script, as it works fine when I run it on another  platform (I'm pretty sure it's Solaris, but I can't swear to that.  It has perl 5.8.8 installed).

So, what am I doing wrong here? How do I get `Net::SMTP::SSL` to work on my Macs?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The tests passed when you installed it?

Comment: Yes, the tests passed when I installed Net::SMTP::SSL with cpan.  I just reproduced the issue on a Mac that hadn't had Net::SMTP::SSL on it so I could capture the output when it is being installed.  See http://pastebin.com/E5nuENyR for what is shown.  Thanks @ikegami!

Comment: wow, this is the entirety of the test suite: `use Test::More tests => 1; use_ok 'Net::SMTP::SSL';`

Comment: Anyway, your question is basically asking how to debug C code. `valgrind perl script.pl` might point you in the right direction.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that it's a bug in the Net::SMTP::SSL perl module?  I tried  running `$ valgrind perl netsmtpssl.pl`, (`netsmtpssl.pl` is the script from my original message) but I don't have `valgrind` on my machine (Mac OS X 10.8.2 with the current version of Xcode installed).

Comment: or something deeper, yes. Even if there's a bug in the script, it shouldn't give a memory allocation error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @ikegami.  I'll submit a bug against Net::SMTP::SSL.  In the meantime, I was able to get Net::SMTP::TLS to work properly, after applying the patch at http://tonyborries.com/techblog/cpanel-exim-and-perls-netsmtptls/ to it, so I'm back in business.  I'm just glad our SMTP server supports both SSL and TLS!

Comment: This has been submitted as a bug on Net::SMTP::SSL.  The bug is available at https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=83481